# Fantasy Alien world With Girl in Crashlanded ship

Tags: story-identification

All i remember about this book... Or graphic novel I guess.. There's alot of drawings.
Maybe it started with an E.. Or like "world of.." "journey.."
 Black and white. With green color . 
So this girl is in a space pod thing..

She has a AI robot i guess. And she has to explore the planet to find her parents I think.. She meets other character and creatures.

That's all i really remember. I had the hard cover and it was like white with black lines with green coloring..

Comment: [Take a look here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for a list of thing you can add to help with identification.